# Keep a specific dictionary from a json file using python and find where the cursor is

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file and I want to make a counter that every time the day (`day = lastday - today`) (`lastday` is the day that the counter will stop and the `day` will be 0) is 0 then I should remove the specific dictionary from the JSON file from where the dictionaries day will be 0.

I succesfully made the counter but I don't know how to make it remove the specific dictionary from the JSON file. Maybe if I could read where the cursor and in with dicitonary the count day = 0 then all would be better.

Here is the type of JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bla",
        "Lastname": "ftr",
        "date": "20/12/2023"
    },
    {
        "Name": "dfas",
        "Lastname": "fsae",
        "date": "18/12/2023"
    },
    {
        "Name": "john",
        "Lastname": "rapper",
        "date": "18/11/2023"
    }
 ]
```

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import json
import time

def countdown(stop):
    while True:
        difference = stop - datetime.now()
        if difference.days == 0:
            print("Good bye!")
            break
            print("The count is: " + str(difference.days) + " day(s)")
            break

def handling():
    with open('tst.json') as f:    
        data = json.load(f)
        for i in range(len(data)):
          date = data[i]["date"]
          i = i + 1
          x = (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')).days
          print(x)
          if x == 0:
                    print("Here i want to remove the dictionary that counts day = 0)
```

I also tried this but nothing happens:

```
import json

with open('tst.json') as fin:
    your_structure = json.load(fin)
for value in your_structure:
    p = value.pop("date", None)
    print(p)
    print("all done")
```

Comment: What's the point of `i = i + 1`? You never use `i` after that.

Comment: you shouldn't modify a list while looping over it. You should create a new list by appending the elements of the original list to it. If you want to remove an element, just skip it when appending.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I removed them both; you should reasonably expect all answers to be written for Python 3.

Comment: It's really not clear what the code should do, and your prose description has grammatical problems which probably make it harder to guess what you are trying to say. What is the "cursor" in this context? What is the relationship between the two functions in your code? You don't call either of them; but please don't make us guess. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Are you actually asking how to sort the JSON array by date so that you can successively remove the oldest member up until you reach a specified date?

Answer (score 0):

Function `handling` needs some changes. Code is not tested, so be careful:

```
   def handling():
        with open('tst.json') as f:    
            data = json.load(f)
            for i in range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1):
              date = data[i]["date"]
              # i = i + 1 # Not useful
              x = (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')).days
              print(x)
              if x == 0:
                  del data[i]
        
        # data was modified, now it must be saved
        with open('tst.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: No.. that is not help i should create a new list without that element.. i tried this

with open("/home/dimos/organ/json/tst.json", 'r') as file:
 data = json.load(file)
 date_to_remove = '18/12/2023' 
 update_data = [entry for entry in data if entry.get("date") != date_to_remove]
with open("/home/dimos/organ/json/tst.json", 'w') as file:
 json.dump(update_data,file,indent = 2)

but still doesn't help because i cant take the date element i just take the day = 0 element without knowing from where it coming from wich dictionary

Comment: I have edited my code, it didn't work correctly but should now. The important part is to go through the data backwards from last item to first. I wanted to adhere to your original code but of course you can instead create a new list containing only the desired items (which may also be more efficient than deleting items from a list).

Answer (score 0):

I made it, thanks for the answer but what i needed is:

```
def remove():
    with open("/home/dimos/organ/json/tst.json", 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        date_to_remove = '18/12/2023' #
        update_data = [entry for entry in data if entry.get("date") != date_to_remove]
    with open("/home/dimos/organ/json/tst.json", 'w') as file:
        json.dump(update_data,file,indent = 2)
```